# Pytorch - Porting @ Operator

Tags: pytorch

I have the following line of code I want to port to Torch Matmul

```
rotMat = xmat @ ymat @ zmat
```

Can I know if this is the correct ordering:

```
rotMat = torch.matmul(xmat, torch.matmul(ymat, zmat))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the python docs on operator precedence the `@` operator has left-to-right associativity

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

> Operators in the same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which groups from right to left).

Therefore the equivalent operation is

```
rotMat = torch.matmul(torch.matmul(xmat, ymat), zmat)
```

Though keep in mind that matrix multiplication is associative (mathematically) so you shouldn't see much of a difference in the result if you do it the other way. Generally you want to associate in the way that results in the fewest computational steps. For example using the naive matrix multiplication algorithm, if X is 1x10, Y is 10x100 and Z is 100x1000 then the difference between

```
(X @ Y) @ Z
```

and

```
X @ (Y @ Z)
```

is about 1*10*100 + 1*100*1000 = 101,000 multiplication/addition operations for the first versus 10*100*1000 + 1*10*1000 = 1,001,000 operations for the second. Though these have the same result (ignoring rounding errors) the second version will be about 10 x slower!

---

As pointed out by @Szymon Maszke pytorch tensors also support the `@` operator so you can still use

```
xmat @ ymat @ zmat
```

in pytorch.

Comment: Might be also valuable to mention that there is no need for `matmul` as @raaj code can be ported directly to `pytorch` via `@` operator mentioned above, e.g. `xmat @ ymat @ zmat`.

Comment: i can't use python 3 as i need to use ROS together in my code. hence the need to avoid @ as per my question